# how to convert all the column headers in a data frame (written in python pandas ) to uppercase

Tags: python, pandas, header, kaggle

[titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLNIO.jpg)

i want to convert all these headers to upper case
I know how to convert one but is there any smart way to convert all i one go?
if so please help me out

It would be a huge help to starters as well

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use this code:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.upper()
```

Read more about this method here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do iterate through each column and apply str.upper() function, by

```
df.columns = [col.upper() for col in df.columns]
```